# Create Google-Maps-API signature with Delphi

Tags: delphi, google-maps-api-3

I would like to create signatures for my maps-for-work clientid. I need to get the geolocation-api running with my clientid. The API is called for example like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&client=gme-myPersonalclientid&signature=HereIsMyProblem
```

I call this link from my Delphi application.

I tried to transfer phyton/java/c# from the official helpsite (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/get-api-key?hl=en) to Delphi but I am still missing something.

```
function TMgrGoogleMap.SignUrl(AUrl: String): String;
Var
  CryptoKey: String;
  Signature: String;
  HMac: TIdHMACSHA1;
  CryptoIDByte: TBytes;
  SignatureHash: TidBytes;
begin
  //  IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary;  // not sure if needed, think not

  CryptoKey := 'ARandomKryptoKeyfY1XbqTib1QlY=';
  CryptoIDByte := TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(CryptoKey);

  HMac := TIdHMACSHA1.Create;
  HMac.Key := TIdBytes(CryptoIDByte);
  SignatureHash := HMac.HashValue(TidBytes(AUrl));

  Signature := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(SignatureHash);

  Result := AUrl + '&signature=' + Signature;
end;
```

As Google-Help code-examples tell, I first decode my cryptokey with Base64, then I create a hash-value with SHA-1 with the encoded cryptokey and the url.

Afterwards I encode it again with Base64 but the result is unfortunately another then the onlinetest https://m4b-url-signer.appspot.com/ gives.

What am I missing? Thanks for every answer in advance.

Comment: The statement `TidBytes(AUrl)` is invalid. You cannot **type-cast** a string to a `TIdBytes` (array of bytes). You have to **encode** the string to bytes (Google requires UTF-8) using `SysUtils.TEncoding.UTF8` or Indy's own `IIdTextEncoding` interface via `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8()`. Also note that Google uses a **modified** base64: "*Modified Base64 for URLs replaces the + and / characters of standard Base64 with - and _ respectively, so that these Base64 signatures no longer need to be URL-encoded*", so you have to adjust your base64 strings when using `TNetEncoding.Base64`.